# How to send a notification to multiple app users on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have implemented facebook notification api.

this is it.

```
 $notiData = array('href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/',
            'access_token'=> $app_token,
            'template'=> 'test' );

 $noti = $facebook->api('/userId/notifications','POST',$notiData);
```

my problem is how to send a notification to multiple/ all app users at once?
how to implement RECIPIENT'S IDS?

I tried like this

```
 $noti = $facebook->api('/10343603789032,123404256614081/notifications','POST',$notiData);
```

above method didn't work.

Comment: Well, you could simply loop over all your users and send the notifications like that - it might take a couple of seconds (depending on how many users you're talking about) - but it will work. Perhaps another option would be [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

Comment: @Lix : Can i use crone jobs for the sending notifications? What i want is, I will add 3 new mobile numbers per day from my admin panel. when it inserted notification should be sent. (New mobile number added.. please check it.. blah blah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is that you should be sending individual unique notifications to users, customised to them, i.e.

> "Your friend Jack has sent you a magic sheep. Click to accept it".

As opposed to:

> You have a new request in your inbox.

Remember, personalising it will help keep your click-through rate high. If your click through rate is low, you'll be blocked from sending notifications.

However, to answer your question, you can use the Batch request API to send multiple notifications in the one request.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

But I recommend you put some thought into making each notification unique. You can and should still use the batch API if you're sending out large amounts of notifications even if they're unique.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'll try and i'll comment on here if i need more help.